# What does "gx-" prefix stands for in ant design

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, custom-theme

I am working on a reactjs app and was looking for editing the font size of some specific text and found the class `gx-fs-sm`. That should suffice what I need, but I am still trying to understand what the prefix "gx-" stands for. Is it something that can be changed or is much more for not colliding with other frameworks or custom classes that you may already be using ?

Looking over the documentation I did not get to the answer in the time I had and therefore this question. If you have other resource/article that explain succinctly the logic behind, please do share!

Comment: The one that made the CSS containing that class can answer what `gx-` stands for, though in general, it can be anything between belonging to a given UI and someone's initials. Asking us because you did not get to the answer in the time you had, is completely off topic.

Comment: @LGSon I am asking about a class that is seems to exist from the antd  framework's lib. This specific class does not exist in the project as a standalone definition. My thought was that it is a library convention, but it may also be a developer's custom extension.

Comment: If it belongs to "antd", they can answer that, if it's not theirs, they tell you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @LGSon comment, after more digging I found out that the `gx-` prefix is not an [antd design](https://ant.design/) class. The app is build on top of [Wieldy](https://themeforest.net/item/wieldy-react-redux-ant-design-admin-template/22719616) custom theme and the class is added by it.
The prefix is declared in /src/styles/global/variables.less.

(Note: While I believe this is trivial for frontend devs, still it is an answer to my question)